# How to convert a string to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I would like to use this code in my cf7:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/go'; 
$errorMessage = 'This is my link, please <a href=\''.$url.'\'>Click here</a>';
```

But the link is not clickable.

[image]

Comment: You should append the code as HTML, but it seems this binds as text.

Comment: That looks like php code not JavaScript as question is tagged

Answer (score 0):

`contact-form-7` does not support HTML for `error messages`, please follow this [link](https://contactform7.com/2016/01/27/html-is-not-allowed-in-messages/) for a better solution.

Basically, you will need to add your HTML content manually in your form and use CSS to display it when the form is `invalid`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: click here]
Please go in admin contact form7 settings.